# Using enums and switch statements to control method execution

Tags: java, methods, enums, getter

My question concerns a specific design convention for methods in Java... but really it would apply to C++, C# and others as well.  I don't know what this convention is called, but if there is a standardized convention, I would like to know how to find it.  In other words, I wish to describe this convention as I have encountered it and be directed to a place where I can learn more.

Consider java.util.Calendar, specificlaly its child, GregorianCalendar.  It has an interesting "getter / setter" convention.  Let's say that you instantiate this object:

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
```

The fields of cal now describe the instant in time (down to the millisecond) at which the constructor was called.

Now let's say that you want to access the year field or the month field.  You would use the following getters.

```
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

Notice that it's not cal.getYear() or cal.getMonth().  It looks like there is only one getter method for this class and that the return value is determined by the parameter naming the desired field.  I would imagine that within the class there is an enum set up to list the fields... and that the getter function itself is composed of some kind of switch statement.

This type of architecture is not described in any of my books... it is however something that I've been using in my current work... but I've been doing it "my" way (basically just making it up as I go along).  If there is a standardized way of doing this that other people use... I'd sure love to know it.  Specifically, using enums and switch statements to control the execution of methods.

Thanks so much for your time!  This is my first question on this site... I have been a long time lurker though.  :)

Comment: allow me to say that I simply HATE this way of doing things. Calendar.getYear or getMonth is way better. Just because your class can have hundreds of getters and setters, it's not a reason to send a parameter to specify the return value. IMO, I think this is a very bad practice.

Comment: You mentionned it correctly. You will use a combination of enum and switch statement to return the correct value. Do you have a particular example you have tried?

Comment: I can imagine it being like that because of different calendars. What if I come up with a calendar not doing that overrated 'month' thing? Instead a year is four times as long (no leap days) and then have '1th winter', '1th spring' etc. Then there wouldn't be a method for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, note that the two approaches to API design are not mutually exclusive: one could have both a "get by index" and a "get by name", i.e.

```
int y1 = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int y2 = cal.getYear();
```

The primary driving force behind getters controlled by an `int` constant in the `Calendar` class is uniformity: it lets users of the `Calendar` class, such as the date formatters, build code that accesses the calendar by index, without further interpretation. For example, if you wanted to implement a formatter that takes a format string and stores a data structure to pull data from a calendar, you would be able to do it with an array of integers: `"dd-mm-yyyy"` would become `int[] {Calendar.DAY, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.YEAR}`, and you would be able to get the data from calendar with a simple `for` loop.

Note that one of the reasons why `Calendar` uses integer constants instead of `enum`s is backward compatibility: that Java did not have `enum` at the time when the `Calendar` class has been introduced.

Also note that you do not need a `switch` statement on an `enum` or `int` constants to implement `Calendar`'s getters and setters: they can be implemented as direct reads and writes of the calendar component array.

Comment: That's interesting... what are your thoughts on making a standard practice of putting all field variables in an ArrayList<Object>?  I guess with a parallel enum naming the indices?

Comment: @user3683532 That wouldn't be a good practice for most "hand-coded" classes, because a lot of efficiency, both in terms of the memory use and the CPU, would be lost. You could go with something like that for "cookie-cutter" classes, though, such as data transfer and data access object covers for rows in a database.

Answer (score 0):

Actually those are not enums. Those are integers instead. Here is the source code of the Calender get method:

```
public int get(int field)
    {
        complete();
        return internalGet(field);
    }
```

But having a single method accepting a ENUM and returning different values based on that, is good practice.

As far as the design pattern goes, IMHO it is a variation of `Factory` pattern.

Comment: Even more interesting is that internalGet simply returns fields[field], so the parameter is really just an index into the internal array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not actually aware of a name for this specific design, although I've seen it used in a few places. It's certainly not one of the standard "Design Patterns" and is really too small to qualify as a design pattern in its own right. It's just a different way of achieving encapsulation over the more traditional way with multiple getters and setters.

If I was to call it something it would probably be something like "flexible getter" or "extensible getter". I.e. "Rather than having multiple setters lets have one flexible getter"

If I was implementing something like this I would probably use the strategy pattern to do it though:

```
 public abstract class Getter<T> {
     private T getData(MyCalendar ob);
 }

 public static final Getter<Integer> MONTH {
      Integer getData(MyCalendar ob) {
          return ob.month;
      }
 }
```

Then your get method just looks like:

```
 <T>public T get(Getter<T> toGet) {
      return toGet.getData(this);
 }
```

This uses polymorphism to fetch the data rather than a massive switch statement. It is fully flexible and extensible while still being type safe, etc.